# run libgdx project (gradle-project) in offline mode

Tags: android, gradle, intellij-idea, libgdx, offline

I have a libgdx project (which is basically a gradle project) and I want to achieve the following.

I'm having a computer with **NO INTERNET** at all.
I want to run (and develop) this project on this computer.

**What have I done:**

I created the project with a computer that has internet connection.
I imported everything that was necessary and built the project successfully.
I set everything else up to be able to start(run) the project.

I copied .android to OFFLINE-PC
I copied .gradle to OFFLINE-PC
I copied android-sdk to OFFLINE-PC
I copied the complete project to OFFLINE-PC
I "opened" the copied project.
I pointed to android-sdk etc.

**What error do I get:**

Could not download gradle.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha11): No cached version available for offline mode.

**Question:**

What do I need to do/copy (what so ever) to get the project running?

(If any additional info is needed then please comment!)

Comment: I'm on Windows, but in my user directory there is a `/Users/James/.gradle` directory that includes the offline daemon and cached versions.  On *nix systems this is probably `~/.gradle`.  Also, my build folder has it's own .gradle dir, as well as a `gradle` folder with the gradle wrapper.

Comment: I'm also on windows and copied the $USERDIR/.gradle directory to the OFFLINE-PC

Comment: Are you building it using an installed version of gradle or the gradle wrapper (gradlew) of the project?

Comment: I'm using the recommended gradle wrapper